# Force maven to run tests in a Spring Boot app with a specific jdk

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven, maven-toolchains-plugin

I'm running Ubuntu 22.04 right now, and trying to use [maven toolchains](https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-using-toolchains.html) to compile a Java 17 Spring Boot project while my active jdk is JDK11. I set up my toolchains so they use JDK18 to compile it, and this works great. However, when I try to actually run the tests (with `mvn clean install`), I get the following error:

> ...ApplicationTests has been compiled by a more recent version of the Java Runtime (class file version 61.0), this version of the Java Runtime only recognizes class file versions up to 55.0

Everything works out fine when I run `mvn clean install -DskipTests`. I can see the testCompile goal executing and the test classes being compiled. I'm guessing the issue is that, after compilation with JDK18, maven still tries to use JDK11 to actually run the tests. Any idea how I can tell maven to run the tests with the correct JDK, when I do `mvn clean install` or similar?

Edit: I managed to get it to work by hardcoding my JDK18 path for the maven surefire plugin. It looks like this:

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0-M7</version>
            <configuration>
                <jvm>/usr/lib/jvm/java-18-openjdk-amd64/bin/java</jvm>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

While this is alright, I don't like the hardcoding. According to the [documentation](https://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/java9.html#head3) (seems out of date, but eh), `maven-surefire-plugin` should be toolchain aware, and should be able to work if I specify my toolchain with something like

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0-M7</version>
            <configuration>
                <jdkToolchain>
                    <version>18</version>
                    <vendor>sun</vendor>
                </jdkToolchain>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

or not even that, since surefire should be able to derive this from the toolchain I configure with the `maven-toolchains-plugin`. Relevant toolchain config, just for the record:

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-toolchains-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>toolchain</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <configuration>
                <toolchains>
                    <jdk>
                        <version>18</version>
                        <vendor>sun</vendor>
                    </jdk>
                </toolchains>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

Comment: Did you specify java.version in the pom?

Comment: @NathanHughes yes, java.version is set to 17

Comment: Is you target execution environment JDK11 ? If so use JDK18 and define `<maven.compiler.release>11</maven.compiler.release>` and no toolchains needed... Can you give more details why you need toolchains etc.?

Comment: @khmarbaise I'm just experimenting with it. I have a few applications running on my system that break if I change my system JDK (what you get when executing `java -version`) to anything other than 11. I'm working on a project that is Java 17 though, so I can't compile it via command line unless I change the java version temporarily to 17+. Not a big deal for me, just an inconvenience, and I'm trying to use toolchains to alleviate it.